# AFCI Breaker with a two wire switch with no power to it going to a box for the ceiling light with new three wire power

Tags: afci

I have an existing two wire switch box that is going to a ceiling junction box where there is new three wire power and another two wire connection to an outlet.  I want to install a new light.

I purchased a new switch that has a ground screw. I connected the white wire from the switch to the black wire on the new light and the black wire from the switch to the new power.  There is no where to ground the new switch so that was left with no wire attached.

Turn the new AFCI breaker on and it does not trip but when I turn on the switch it pops the breaker.  Any thoughts?

Comment: We need a photo of the wiring, if you only have 2 wires at the switch box. This is a switch leg and the wrong place to try to add another switch / light. In this case the white should be the always hot and the black should be the switched hot going back to the existing light. Code requires the white to be reidentified by marking the white with tape or marker and n a color other than gray, green or white but this step is not done by many.

Comment: How do i add a picture or file to my question?

Comment: @Clayton, you will have to post the image on imgur or some other image sharing site first and then link that picture in your question using the "edit" link right under the question.  Once you get a higher reputation score you can upload images directly.

Comment: What does "new 3-wire power" mean?

Comment: When you [edit] your post, look along the top edge of the edit box for a "mountains and sun" icon.   That will let you insert a photo.

Comment: Can you post photos please, especially of the insides of the boxes?

Comment: And don't forget to post, where you live, because regulatory statements and also wire coloring differ vastly between countries.